# Laravel 4 Eloquent database save in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a cron task in my Laravel 4 project that gets data from an API and stores it to the db using `Eloquent`. I need it to do this for every user stored in my users table. I figured I could iterate over each user, get the data and `$this->save()` it within my model. Only the last record is being added.

I did a simple test:

```
$this->user_id = 23;
$this->save();
$this->user_id = 43;
$this->save();
```

and still only the last entry is being added. Clearly I'm not using Eloquent properly or something. Should I not be using Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only updating your model ($this) each run of the loop, so only the last value will be shown.

You should create one record each time instead :

```
Model::create([
    "user_id" => 23
]);
```

Where Model is your Eloquent model.

Comment: Interesting; technically the docs do specify to create a new Model prior to save. I figured `$this->key` would be overwritten each iteration so I wouldn't have to create a new model instance. Thanks!